# Using install_name_tool what's going wrong?

Tags: macos, install-name-tool

I'm trying to change the install path of a dylib after it has been built. I use `otool -L` to check what the current path is. And then I do:

```
$ install_name_tool -change /my/current/path/libmine.dylib \
    /my/new/path/libmine.dylib libmine.dylib
```

I don't get an error, but nothing changes. If I check the path again the old one is still there. Also the new path is a lot shorter then the old one, so no problem there, and I think the lib is even compiled with extra flag for more filepath space.

Any ideas?

Comment: To check just the install name, use `otool -D`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The man page for install_name_tool says that -change is for dependencies.  You're trying to change the name of the library itself.

Having just experimented, I found I couldn't change the name of a dylib that appears inside the dylib itself but I could change the names of other dependencies.

Having experimented more: `install_name_tool -id newname file` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks I overlooked that because all the example code I found was related to dependencies.